# Facebook Registration Process

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, coldfusion

I have been looking for an answer to my Facebook Registration problem for over an hour now and ironically, I cannot seem to find a relevant answer.

I am creating a Freelancing Review website that will utilize Facebook for the login process and hopefully the registration process as well. There is plenty of easy to find code on the login process but I am struggling with the registration process.

I came across the following a URL (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v1.0) that described a Facebook Registration Plugin. However, this feature is deprecated and will be removed as of April 30, 2015 so this is not really a solution to my problem.

The deprecation notice links another URL (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2) describing the Facebook Login feature. The problem with this is that if the user does not have a Facebook account, then the user is never prompted to create one after clicking the Facebook Login button. If the user has a Facebook account, it works great.

Freelancers come from all parts of the world and I do not know how many of them have Facebook accounts. I would like to allow those particular Freelancers who do not have a Facebook account an easy way to create one without leaving my review website. Ideally, I would want to avoid redirecting them to Facebook to create an account even with a new tab window; I would like to use some JavaScript SDK, a ColdFusion based SDK, or even a PHP based SDK to get the Facebook Registration working.

So in a nutshell, how do I allow Facebook Registration for new Facebook users on my website without redirecting them to Facebook itself now that the Facebook Registration Plugin has been removed?

Thanks in advance for any information!

Comment: good questions. following.

Comment: While I would prefer that the Facebook Registration process be JavaScript based like the Facebook Login Process, I did happen to find an alternative solution. When the user clicks the register with facebook button on my website, I can use OAuth2 to open a new tab, redirect using the current tab, or use a pop-up  to the Facebook website. The user completes registration and is redirected back to my website. I hate pop-ups with a passion so I will probably use the new tab approach but also update the previous tab after registration has completed. It is less than ideal but I suppose it will work.